# Selecting a DatagridColumnHeader selects an item on the list

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid with checkbox. When an item is selected, the checkbox is checked and the row is highlighted. When I clicked the DataGridColumnHeader while there are items selected, the selected items are added again on the SelectedItems of the DataGrid. So if I currently have 2 SelectedItems, if I click the DataGridColumnHeader, the SelectedItems count would be 4 - the added items are a duplicate of the selected items.

I do not know why the SelectedItems is updated whenever I click DataGridColumnHeader. I have an IsSelected property on my Model. I tried to debug to know which is updating the selection then I got this external code below:

```
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.SetValue(object item, object value) + 0x1c5 bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateSource(object value) + 0xce bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.UpdateValue() + 0xa9 bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Dirty() + 0x7a bytes    
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value) + 0x3e bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType, bool isInternal) + 0x3b1 bytes  
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value) + 0x99 bytes    
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.AdjustNewContainers() + 0x11d bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.SetStatus(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorStatus value) + 0xb0 bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.BatchGenerator.System.IDisposable.Dispose() + 0x22 bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl(System.Windows.Size constraint, ref double? lastPageSafeOffset, ref System.Collections.Generic.List<double> previouslyMeasuredOffsets, bool remeasure) + 0x1e83 bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint) + 0x106 bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint) + 0x3b bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x313 bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x521 bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout() + 0x569 bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(object arg) + 0x22 bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks() + 0x96 bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(object resizedCompositionTarget) + 0xdf bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(object resizedCompositionTarget) + 0x2f bytes   
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0x5a bytes 
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) + 0x47 bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl() + 0x281 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x285 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x9 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x57 bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() + 0x71 bytes  
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() + 0x2e3 bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) + 0xb3 bytes 
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) + 0x14a bytes   
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) + 0x80 bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0x5a bytes 
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) + 0x47 bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs) + 0x2bc bytes 
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) + 0x140 bytes    
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) + 0x112 bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window) + 0x17a bytes    
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run() + 0x67 bytes 
UpgradeStudio.exe!UpgradeStudio.App.Main() + 0x70 bytes C#
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x57 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x285 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x9 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x57 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x51 bytes   
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

How can I prevent the row to be selected when I click DataGridColumnHeader? Please help me. Thanks!